# Let $f\in C^2( \mathbb R)$ , then is it true that the function $F:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ , $F(x,y)=\Big(xf(\|(x,y)\|),yf(\|(x,y)\|)\Big)$ , is?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a $C^2$ function , then is it true  that the function $F:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ defined by

$F(x,y)=\Big(xf\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right),yf\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\Big)$ , is the gradient of some function i.e. does there

exist a function $g:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ such that $\nabla g=F$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Let $\vec{r} = (x,y)$ and $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. Then $F$ is the gradient of the function

$$g(\vec{r}) = \int_0^r sf(s)\, ds.$$

For

$$\nabla g = \frac{\vec{r}}{r} g'(r) = \frac{\vec{r}}{r}(rf(r)) = \vec{r}f(r) = F.$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you got the expressions for  $\nabla g$ ?

Comment: It's by the chain rule.

Comment: I don't understand the $\nabla g = \dfrac{\vec r}{r} g'(r )$ part ..

Comment: That's the one where the chain rule is used. Indeed

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} \frac{d g}{d r} = \frac{x}{r}g'(r)$$

and similarly $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = \frac{y}{r}g'(r)$. Thus 

$$\nabla g = \left(\frac{x}{r}g'(r), \frac{y}{r}g'(r)\right) = \frac{\vec{r}}{r}g'(r).$$

Comment: But , $\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ does not exist at $(0,0)$

Comment: That was for the case $r > 0$. To show that $\nabla g(0,0) = (0,0)$, consider that $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(0,0)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{g(x,0) - g(0,0)}{x-0} =\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}\int_0^{|x|} sf(s)\, ds = 0.$$ The last step follows from computing the one-sided limits separately and using the fundamental theorem of calculus. Similarly, $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\bigg|_{(0,0)} = 0$. Therefore $\nabla g(0,0) = (0,0) = F(0,0)$.